# CD into directory via script executed by .bashrc function

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a program which will let me cd into a directory. My program is called mangy, I also have a mangy.sh script and a mangy function defined in .bashrc

mangy.sh is as follows

```
out= $($HOME/.mangy/mangy $@)
if [ "$1" == "g" ] || [ "$1" == "go" ] ; then 
    cd "$out"
else
    echo "$out"
fi
```

and here is my function in .bashrc

```
function mangy() {
   source $HOME/.mangy/mangy.sh $@
}
export -f mangy
```

`~/Desktop` is an example of what`out` would contain

When I run the `mangy` function it outputs `/home/ryan/Desktop: Is a directory`
 but doesn't navigate me there. I swear I had this working at one point but can't remember how I did it

Comment: Do you really have that space after `out=`?  If so, that part won't work at least

Comment: That was it, thanks!

Comment: Why do you put the code in a file if it needs a function to work properly? Just inline all the code into the function.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to source the parameter. Sourcing a script is different from  executing it. Sourcing just includes the file, so this should do:

```
function mangy() {
   source $HOME/.mangy/mangy.sh
}
```

Also, you should quote the `$@` if you don't want it to be split by spaces.

```
out=$($HOME/.mangy/mangy "$@")
```

Also, it may be simpler not to have `mangy.sh` at all, though it's really your decision. You can put it directly in `.bashrc`.

```
function mangy() {
    out= $($HOME/.mangy/mangy $@)
    if [ "$1" == "g" ] || [ "$1" == "go" ] ; then 
        cd "$out"
    else
        echo "$out"
    fi
}
```